# How to check if user has shared website on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is what I did but nothing happens when the I click on the share on facebook link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
 <head>
    <title>Sample Facebook share</title>
 </head>
<body> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '1407416289470597',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.0'
  });
};


      (function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function test() 
{    
    FB.ui(
      {
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://www.mywebsite.com',
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_code) {
          alert('Posting completed.');
        } else {
          alert('Error while posting.');
        }
      }
    );
}

</script>

<a href="" onClick="test()">Share</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Nothing happens when I click on the Share link.

I don't know what's wrong. I copy-pasted [this](http://www.writeyourcode.com/share-with-facebook-feed-dialog-2/) example as well, still nothing.

Tested it on a VPS with SSL and on a shared server as well.

Comment: Guys anyhing? I tried to use plugins as well (like sharrre) and simply nothing appears on my page

Answer (score 0):

The Feed Dialog is deprecated, as shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0

You're better off with implementing the new Share Dialog. You can find the guide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

The SDK initialization also should call the new sdk.js file:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.0'
  });
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated my post with the full code. Nothing happens when I click the share link. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: See my update. You must include the `sdk.js` file, not the `all.js` anymore.

Comment: It's crazy, still nothing... I don't know what else to do. I added the website platform to the Facebook app but haven't submitted it to Facebook. I don't know if I should have done this but least something should happen when I click the link (the function itself is called).

Comment: Please try this sample code: http://pastebin.com/1vs53ihc. Also, check you app settings, web platform url settings and app domains.